# reload datatable content

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i do have a code which run on the page. Page contains 3 tabs, and each tab contains a table and 2 date input fields plus button to send request. JS looks something like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tbl1 = $("tbl1").dataTable(){ //a lots of parametres}
    .. //2 more tbl2 and tbl3 variable initialization

    $("btn1").click(function(){
        tbl1.fnReloadAjax(tbl.oSettings());
    });
    ..//2 more btn2 and btn3 action initialization
})
```

On first time page load, date input fields have span 10 days and table contain record for last 10 days. Now I did some changes, i do have a new ajax request which remove record from server and I need to update table content.
there is a button in each row and press on it removes this record on server. Everything works just fine but to see changes need to reload full page.
I have tried to do in this way:

```
function removeData(source){
     $.post('delete_record',{}, function ...)// ajax request to remove data
     alert("deleted");  // notice to user that record was deleted
     tbl1.fnReloadAjax(tbl1.oSettings()); // ERROR no ref to tbl1(trying to update table content)
}
```

error is becouse inside removeData function ref to tbl1 object doesnot exist, becouse tbl1 is defined inside $(document).ready function. how i can get link to tbl1 out

I have tried right now to take table initialization code out of function ready(). Something like

```
var getoTabele = function(){
  var oTable = $("tbl1").dataTable..... //initialization code
  ...
  ...
  return oTable;
}
```

Now I can use oTable inside of removeData function becouse I can get link inside removeData function

```
var oTable = getoTable() // Data warning. Cannot reinitialise DataTable
```

which is right becouse function getoTable create new oTable not ref to the old one

Answer (score 2):

Use `bRetrieve` param:

```
function removeData(source){
     (...)

     // this will return the previous, already initialized dataTable object.
     var tbl1 = $("tbl1").dataTable({'bRetrieve':true});

     tbl1.fnReloadAjax(tbl1.oSettings()); 
}
```

Comment: this is great :). I did find solution myself but it is complicated and I was using singleton pattern and checking was oTable initialised or not .

Comment: this is much better that my solution more neat and clean. Thanks a lot and I am sorry, I did mistake and pressed that you help wasnt helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your `tblN` variables outside the `$(document).ready()`, then you will acess them in your functions :

```
var tbl1, tbl2, tbl3;
$(document).ready(function(){
    // **** //
    tbl1 = $("tbl1").dataTable();
});

function removeData() {
    // **** //
    tbl1.fnReloadAjax(tbl1.oSettings());    
}
```